# PHP: Display database datetime based on user's login location's timezone

Tags: php

database date is display as

```
2017-12-01UTC05:01:26 AM
```

as based on my location I want to display it as

```
 12-01-2017 10: 57 AM
```

how it can be done please help
the time is display according to login timezone
like in america it display different time and india different

```
$date_added = $application['log_in_time'];
 $the_date = strtotime($application['log_in_time']);
 $datetime = (date("Y-d-mTH:i:s A", $the_date) . "<br />"); 
 echo $datetime;
```

then it display the

```
 2017-12-01UTC05:01:26 AM
```

and in this strtotime function display

```
01.01.1970 12:00 am
```

ALSO

if I use directly strtotime function in db date display as

```
01-12-2017 05:01
```

instead of `05:01 AM` 
 I want to display time using my location i.e it will be `10:57 AM`

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not You go for the strtotime function

**date("d.m.Y h:i a", strtotime($sdate));**

```
$sdate="2017-12-01UTC05:01:26 AM";
```

echo date("d.m.Y h:i a", strtotime($sdate));

Comment: $date_added = $application['log_in_time'];
     $the_date = strtotime($application['log_in_time']);
     $datetime = (date("Y-d-mTH:i:s A", $the_date) . "<br />");
     echo $datetime;
     then it display the  2017-12-01UTC05:01:26 AM and in this strtotime function display 
     01.01.1970 12:00 am

Comment: if I use directly strtotime function in db date display as  01-12-2017 05:01
   instead of 05:01 AM i want to display time using my location i.e it will be 10:57 AM

Comment: What was your timezone meow

Comment: I have used this also
    
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d h:m:i");
    
 buts it's wrong I want it display based on users timezone and detect automatically
 I also tried this
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Comment: I think then we have to first get the timezone that the user is from and set the timezone according to that. after that we can form the strtotime function

Comment: date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get())

Comment: after echo it display 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132969/discussion-between-rajesh-baskaran-and-meow).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 $sdate="2017-12-01UTC05:01:26 AM";
 echo  date("m-d-Y H:i", strtotime($sdate));
 ?>
```

[Answer Demo](https://eval.in/714730)